# Can't use the variable from functions.php in header.php

Tags: wordpress

I have this simple global variable for calling image path. I put it in `functions.php` so it can be used in any pages.

```
// Inside functions.php
$img = get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/img/';

// Inside header.php
<img src="<?php echo $img; ?>my-image.jpg">
```

But that variable returns **empty** when I call it inside `header.php`. Weirdly, it works fine when I call it in other template page like `index.php`.

I tried googling but the result always about the generic PHP `header(Location)`.

Any solution for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this function to your `functions.php`:

```
function img()
{
    return get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/img/';
}
```

and use this in your `header.php` like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo img(); ?>my-image.jpg">
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, it works. Do you know why variable doesn't work but function does?

Answer (score 2):

You can define it global (in header) before using it such as:

```
<?php 
// Inside functions.php
$img = get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/img/';

// Inside header.php
global $img;
?>
<img src="<?php echo $img; ?>my-image.jpg">
```

It should work.

Although @Ankit Agrawal's solution is recommended.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but when googling I found some people saying that `global` variable is bad. So I will follow Ankit answer

Comment: You are right. That is why, i also recommended the same. All the best :)