# Inserting variable into header

Tags: wordpress, header

I have setup a custom template and `functions.php` such that which users can insert an image url. The is for this image to be displayed in the header.

In the custom template, I use an `add_action` to place the image into the header. My problem is that whilst I can supply a url directly in the custom template with this image showing up, the same url inserted as a variable does not work.

So, the following extract from my custom template works (where $featimage is set to the url of the image)

```
$page_id = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();

$memoptions = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_my_meta',TRUE);

function img(){
    $featimage="http://etc.jpg";
    return $featimage;

}


function memberland_featured_image() {
    $catchkathmandu_featured_image = '<div id="header-featured-image">';        
    $catchkathmandu_featured_image .= '<img id="main-feat-img" class="wp-post-image"    alt="" src="'.img().'" />';
$catchkathmandu_featured_image .= '</div><!-- #header-featured-image -->';      

echo $catchkathmandu_featured_image;
}

 add_action( 'catchkathmandu_after_hgroup_wrap', 'memberland_featured_image', 10 );

get_header();
```

but here where `$featimgage` is set to the variable from the metabox it does not work.

```
$page_id = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();

$memoptions = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_my_meta',TRUE);

function img(){
    $featimage=$memoptions['memberland_ftd_hder_image'];
    return $featimage;

}


function memberland_featured_image() {
    $catchkathmandu_featured_image = '<div id="header-featured-image">';        
    $catchkathmandu_featured_image .= '<img id="main-feat-img" class="wp-post-image"    alt="" src="'.img().'" />';
$catchkathmandu_featured_image .= '</div><!-- #header-featured-image -->';      

echo $catchkathmandu_featured_image;
}

 add_action( 'catchkathmandu_after_hgroup_wrap', 'memberland_featured_image', 10 );

get_header();
```

p.s. I am using the function img() as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18888271/cant-use-the-variable-from-functions-php-in-header-php) as without it, inserting $featimage directly into the src, even if pre-defined as the url, did not work.

I know that the variable options from them the metaboxes are working as images etc which I want displaying under the header all function.

Is this something to do with the order of wordpress functions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the img() function does not know about $memoptions variable as the variable is defined outside the scope of the img() function.

you can define $memoptions in img() function as below:

```
function img(){
    $memoptions = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_my_meta',TRUE);
    $featimage=$memoptions['memberland_ftd_hder_image'];
    return $featimage;
}
```